# Are the columns used for creating table index, implicitly UNIQUE?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have created a table in MYSQL with below columns

```
create table Students (
        id varchar(32) not null,
        name varchar(200),
        key1 varchar(450),
        key2 varchar(255),
        key3 varchar(255),
        key4 varchar(255)
)
```

Now, i have created index for this table as

```
create index Students_key_inx on Students (key1(255));
```

Now, i haven't mentioned uniqueness for key1. Since, I believe index column should have unique values, so will MYSQL enforce uniqueness automatically ? Meaning, would I not be able to insert duplicate values for `key1` in `Students` ?

Comment: why do you think the unique keyword exists?

Comment: @e4c5 I know about unique keyword and its usage, all I am asking is if the index enforces it implicitly

Comment: simple matter of making two inserts to find out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating an index does not enforce uniqueness.  Creating a *unique* index does:

```
create unique index unq_students_key1 on Students (key1(255));
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX student_key1 ON Students (key1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitions (simplified)

- Index: An ordered collection of values stored in the columns used to build the index. This helps the rdbms to find specific values in the table without the need of checking the data in the table itself (in which it can be in any order or not ordered in any ways and usually requires more IO operations)
- Unique: This is a CONSTRAINT which defines a rule what kind of data can be stored in the database.

So these are different concepts, you have to explicitly tell if you want a unique index. Also please keep in mind, that NULL values are considered as different values.